# How to match "\n" in Poco::RegularExpression C++?

Tags: c++, regex, pcre, poco-libraries

My current code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Foundation.h>
#include <Poco/RegularExpression.h>

int main()
{
    Poco::RegularExpression regex("[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+");
    Poco::RegularExpression::MatchVec mvec;
    constad std::string astring = "ABC\nDEFG";

    int matches = regex.match(astring,0,mvec);

    std::cout << "Hello World\n";

    return 0;
 }
```

The position of the '\n' in the string I am trying to match can be, a single space, multiple spaces, or new line(hence why I am using whitespace meta character).

The number of matches returned is zero. Is there a flag I need to set or something?

Comment: Double up the backslash, since `\s` is not a recognized escape sequence in string literal.

Comment: Isn't that _line-end_ `$` for regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the scape sequence in your regex.

In this case you want to add a backslash (`\`) into the string `astring`, using the token `\s`, but in C/C++ or Java it must be writen as double `\\`. So, to fix your problem you must add another backslash:

```
Poco::RegularExpression regex("[A-Z]+\\s+[A-Z]+");
```

Here you can find the reference:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Poco::RegularExpression s ("\\s"); // White char
Poco::RegularExpression n ("\\n"); // New line
Poco::RegularExpression r ("\\r"); // Carrige return
Poco::RegularExpression t ("\\t"); // Tabulator
```